# Remove parts of a path using parameter expansion... but how?

Tags: unix-shell, bourne-shell

I need to remove the part

> man1/bmtoa.1.gz

from the full path

> /usr/share/man/man1/bmtoa.1.gz

so that it results in

> /usr/share/man/

I've tried ${path#[!/]*/*} and ${path#/*/*} but both result in wrong paths.

Comment: If you have received an acceptable answer, then please consider accepting it by clicking on the outline of a checkmark to the left of the answer. This will aid future users who have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

this will work `${path%/*/*}`, but works from the back to the front. [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html) is a good how-to for chopping strings in bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you could deal with `/usr/share/man/man1`, then you could do `dirname /usr/share/man/man1/bmtoa.1.gz`, but since you stated that you need the man1 to also come off, so you'll have to daisy-chain them:

```
dirname `dirname /usr/share/man1/bmtoa.1.gz`
```

Comment: It doesn't use shell expansion as requested by to me dirname looks much saner and simpler.